# Scroll to bottom of a list populated with CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-scrollview

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of `List` when a button is tapped. I have tried placing the `List` in a `ScrollViewReader` and this seems to work only when the `List` is populated using an array. When I populate the List using `CoreData`'s `FetchedResults` the `List` doesn't scroll for some reason.

```
var array = Array(0...100)


private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

NavigationView {
        ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
            List{
                ForEach(items) {item in
                    
                    Text(item.text!)
                }
            }
            Button("Tap to scroll") {
                
                    proxy.scrollTo(10, anchor: .top)
            }
    }
}
```

Here if i use `items` it doesn't scroll but when I replace `items` with `array` the list scrolls as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollTo()` works by receiving an identifier, not an index.

Using `array` works because `10` is contained in `array`, but `10` cannot match `item`.

I would suggest you add an ID String property to your objects (I think you could even use `object.uriRepresentation()`) tag your views with that identifier, and now you'll be able to use `scrollTo`.

```
private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

NavigationView {
        ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
            List{
                ForEach(items) {item in
                    Text(item.text!)
                      .id(item.id)
                }
            }
            Button("Tap to scroll") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(items[10].id, anchor: .top)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to use the `.id`. `proxy.scrollTo(items[10], anchor: .top)` works just as well as the view is already keeping track of the objects.